# DataAnnotations range in View number helper

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, data-annotations

I'm using Entity Framework with Data Annotations, in my Model (myModel.cs) i have this field:

```
    [DisplayName("My object")]
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public Int16 myObject { get; set; }
```

In the View I have this Razor helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myObject , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "number",  placeholder = "Type the number of objects" } })
```

Using the code above user can insert the number 1000 and only during the submit the form return a validation error.
I would like to configure the EditorFor Helper in my view for deny the possibility to the user to type any values lower than 1 or greater than 10: for examples using the min and max attribute in htmlAttributes with the values of data annotations, but how to do this?

Comment: you need to use some client side plugins to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent user enter some values on client side you should use **javascript**. For your case you can write it like this (example with html):

```js
    document.getElementsByClassName('restrict-number-range')[0].oninput = function () {
        var max = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-val-range-max'));
        if (parseInt(this.value) > max) {
            this.value = max;
            return; 
        }

        var min = parseInt(this.getAttribute('data-val-range-min'));
        if (parseInt(this.value) < min) {
            this.value = min;
            return; 
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="myObject" class="restrict-number-range" data-val-range-max='10' data-val-range-min='1'/>
```

I just get info from `data` attributes that generated by Html helper. Your helper will look like this (don't forget to add js):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.myObject, 
               new { 
               htmlAttributes = new { 
                     @class = "form-control restrict-number-range", //check class
                     type = "number",  
                     placeholder = "Type the number of objects" 
                     }})
```